# How to draw right arrow symbol in SLD for Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have the below part of SLD:

```
<sld:WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings#0xE0</sld:WellKnownName>
<sld:Fill>
  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</sld:CssParameter>
  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>                                    
</sld:Fill>
```

But it does not work due to lack of Wingding fonts in host server. I am looking for alternative way of drawing right arrow. I tried below using HTML right arrow entity (→):

```
<sld:WellKnownName>&#x2192;</sld:WellKnownName>
```

But geoserver throws exception on that:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified mark → was not found!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what fonts you have on your server this is hard to answer, on my linux box I can get a right arrow using:

```
<sld:WellKnownName>ttf://DejaVu Sans#0x2192</sld:WellKnownName>
```

I found this by hunting through the fonts I have installed in `Character Map` (there is a section called arrows, but there are others under Dingbats). You can download DejaVu Sans from [github](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can try out the custom WKT shape support:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>arrow</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>right arrow style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>right arrow</Title>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>wkt://MULTILINESTRING((0 0.5, 1 0.5), (0.75 0.25, 1 0.5, 0.75 0.75))</WellKnownName>
                <Stroke>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000ff</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>25</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The result being, roughly:

[image]